# RTCPeerConnection is not defined in Nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, webrtc, react-context

I want to use the React context API to pass an instance of RTCPeerConnection to my React Component tree. I am aware of the Nextjs SSR feature, which renders the component first on the server side. I saw in many solutions to this problem that I could use next/dynamic imports to dynamically import React components or load an SDK using Awaited import in useEffect, but none of them fit my needs. Here is the code; please share the best architecture you can think of.

```
//RTCProvider.tsx

import { createContext, useCallback, useReducer } from "react";
import React from "react";

const configuration = {
  iceServers: [
    {
      urls: "stun:stun.l.google.com:13902",
    },
  ],
};



class MyRTCConnection extends RTCPeerConnection {
  public chatChannel: RTCDataChannel;
  public remoteClient: string | object;

  constructor(config: RTCConfiguration) {
    super(config);
    this.chatChannel = this.createDataChannel("chat");
    this.ondatachannel = (event) => {
      const dataChannel = event.channel;
      dataChannel.onopen = () => {
        console.log(
          "peer connection is ready to receive data channel messages"
        );
      };
    };

    this.onconnectionstatechange = (event) => {
      console.log(event);
      if (this.connectionState === "connected") {
        console.log("succesfully connected with other peer");
      }
    };
  }
  async generateOffer(
    offerOption: RTCOfferOptions
  ): Promise<RTCSessionDescriptionInit> {
    // if (!this.getSenders()) {
    //   throw Error("No senders yet");
    // }
    const offer = await this.createOffer(offerOption);
    this.setLocalDescription(offer);
    return offer;
  }

  async acceptAnswer(answer:any){
    this.setRemoteDescription(answer)
  }

  async acceptOfferAndCreateAnswer(
    remoteOffer: any | RTCSessionDescriptionInit
  ): Promise<RTCSessionDescriptionInit> {
    // if (!this.getSenders()) {
    //   throw Error("No senders yet");
    // }
    this.setRemoteDescription(remoteOffer);
    const answer = await this.createAnswer();
    this.setLocalDescription(answer);
    return answer;
  }
  setRemoteClient(data: any): void {
    this.remoteClient = data;
  }
}



const rtcConn = new MyRTCConnection(configuration);


const RTCContext = createContext<MyRTCConnection | null>(rtcConn);


function RTCProvider({ children }: any) {
  
  return (
    <RTCContext.Provider value={rtcConn}>
      {/* <RTCActionContext.Provider value={rtcActions}> */}
        {children}
      {/* </RTCActionContext.Provider> */}
    </RTCContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default RTCProvider;
export { RTCContext };
```

My _app.tsx

```
// src/pages/_app.tsx

import "@/styles/global.css";
import "@/styles/home.css";
import { ReactNode,useContext } from "react";
import type { AppProps, AppLayoutProps } from "next/app";
import { store } from "app/store";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import MediaProvider from "@/app/context/MediaProvider";
import IncomingCallModal from "@/components/modals/IncomingCallModal";
import SocketProvider, { SocketContext } from "@/app/context/SocketProvider";
import RTCProvider, { RTCContext } from "@/app/context/RTCProvider";

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppLayoutProps) {
  
  const getLayout = Component.getLayout || ((page: ReactNode) => page);
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <SocketProvider>
        <MediaProvider>
          <RTCProvider>
            <IncomingCallModal />
            {getLayout(<Component {...pageProps} />)}
          </RTCProvider>
        </MediaProvider>
      </SocketProvider>
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

while importing Provider in the `_app.txs` it throws an error like this:-

```
  12 | 
  13 | 
> 14 | class MyRTCConnection extends RTCPeerConnection {
     |                              ^
  15 |   public chatChannel: RTCDataChannel;
  16 |   public remoteClient: string | object;
  17 | 
ReferenceError: RTCPeerConnection is not defined
```

So I tried this awaited import to import the RTCProvider dynamically in client side;

```
// src/pages/_app.tsx

// import RTCProvider, { RTCContext } from "@/app/context/RTCProvider";
var RTCProvider
(async () => {
  RTCProvider = (await import("@/app/context/RTCProvider")).default;
})();

console.log(RTCProvider); // undefined
```

But the RTCProvider is undefined in the browser console. Making this approach work would be my last move, I am looking for different approaches to handle this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I came upon.

```
 import { createContext, useCallback, useReducer } from "react";
 import React from "react";
 import { store } from "@/app/store";
 import { addChatMessage } from "../store/chatSlice";
 import handleChat from "../store/actionThunks/handleChat";

const configuration = {
  iceServers: [
    {
      urls: "stun:stun.l.google.com:13902",
    },
  ],
};

if (typeof window != "undefined") {
  class MyRTCConnection extends RTCPeerConnection {
    public chatChannel: RTCDataChannel;
    public metaChannel: RTCDataChannel;
    public remoteClient: string | object;

    constructor(config: RTCConfiguration) {
      super(config);
      this.chatChannel = this.createDataChannel("chat");
      this.ondatachannel = (eve) => {
        const dataChannel = eve.channel;

        // Switching by data channel name due
        switch (dataChannel.label) {
          case "chat":
            dataChannel.onmessage = (event) => {
              const message = JSON.parse(event.data);
              store.dispatch(handleChat(message));
            };
        }
      };
      this.onconnectionstatechange = (event) => {
        if (this.connectionState === "connected") {
          console.log("succesfully connected with other peer");
        }
      };
    }
    async generateOffer(
      offerOption: RTCOfferOptions
    ): Promise<RTCSessionDescriptionInit> {
      // if (!this.getSenders()) {
      //   throw Error("No senders yet");
      // }
      const offer = await this.createOffer(offerOption);
      this.setLocalDescription(offer);
      return offer;
    }

    async acceptAnswer(answer: any) {
      this.setRemoteDescription(answer);
    }

    async acceptOfferAndCreateAnswer(
      remoteOffer: any | RTCSessionDescriptionInit
    ): Promise<RTCSessionDescriptionInit> {
      // if (!this.getSenders()) {
      //   throw Error("No senders yet");
      // }
      this.setRemoteDescription(remoteOffer);
      const answer = await this.createAnswer();
      this.setLocalDescription(answer);
      return answer;
    }
    setRemoteClient(data: any): void {
      this.remoteClient = data;
    }
  }

  var rtcConn = new MyRTCConnection(configuration) as MyRTCConnection;

  var RTCContext = createContext<MyRTCConnection | null>(rtcConn);
} else {
  var RTCContext = createContext(rtcConn);
}

function RTCProvider({ children }: any) {
  return <RTCContext.Provider value={rtcConn}>{children}</RTCContext.Provider>;
}

export default RTCProvider;
export { RTCContext };
```

The application is also working fine.

Comment: Nice, so it's just to wrap 'if (typeof window != "undefined")'.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you get undefined in console.log is due to Promise. Which the console prints before RTCProvider promise resolves.

Though not sure which nextJS version you are using, but what you can possibly try is to use next/dynamic. Not sure on import await approach.

```
import dynamic from "next/dynamic"

const RTCProvider = dynamic(() => import("@/app/context/RTCProvider"), {
   ssr: false,
})
```

Then do a print from your RTCProvider.

```
function RTCProvider({ children }: any) {
   console.log('x')
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't aware of this {ssr : false} feature before. Looks like it is going to work fine but I had already sorted this and the code is working fantastically, let me share my code.